# Visual Basic: Calculating days until birthday from today

Tags: vba, date

I need to make a function what calculates days until birthday from todays date.
What I have so far is:

```
Function synnipaev(sk As Date, tana As Date)

synnipaev = DateDiff("d", sk, tana)

End Function
```

sk is birthdate in the Excel sheet (formated as 10.10.2001 DD/MM/YYYY)

tana is todays date in the Excel sheet ( =TODAY() DD/MM/YYYY)

It gives me the days but also includes the years. 
How to make the function not include years?

Comment: What do you mean it also includes the years?

Comment: Like birthdate = 10.10.2001 and today = 10.04.2015. The answer should be 183 but instead it is 4930

Comment: Why would the answer be 183?  The difference between October 4th and October 10th is 6 days.  That doesn't make any sense.  You need to explain a little more about what you expect and how it should work.

Comment: @stocksynd bad idea to use `10.10.2001` for example as it isn't clear which one is the month and which the day.

Comment: Should be more understandable now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DateDiff is simply giving you the total number of days between the two dates.  You need to find the difference between the current date and the ***next*** birthdate:

```
Public Function DaysToBirthday(birthday As Date) As Integer

    Dim targetYear As Integer

    'Has the birthday already passed this year?
    If Month(Now) > Month(birthday) Or _
       (Month(Now) = Month(birthday) And Day(Now) > Day(birthday)) Then
        'Then use next year.
        targetYear = Year(Now) + 1
    Else
        targetYear = Year(Now)
    End If

    DaysToBirthday = CInt(DateSerial(targetYear, Month(birthday), Day(birthday)) - Now)

End Function
```

Note: VBA stores Date variables as Doubles, with days to the left of the decimal and time to the right. If all you care about are days, you can save the function call and do a simple subtraction.

Comment: Looks great! Thanks! But it gives a negative value if birthdates day is a greater value than todays days value. For example birthdate = 30.01.2001 and today = 10.04.2015 gives a -70